# filling textview while button state is down

Tags: android

i want to fill the TextView with character while Button is Down 
i wrote this code but it just writes one character  ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    final TextView tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                String s = tv.getText().toString();
                tv.setText( s + "E");
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

how can i fill the textview with a character while button state is down ?

Comment: Why do you not use `setOnClickListener`?

Comment: Here you can find what you need: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/XObZeVaVJHI

Comment: @Gunaseelan Because he wants it to repeat the action while button is pressed all the time as far as I understand.

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki I am really sorry. I just saw the code and comes to assumption without read the full question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.. Here is the solution. Tried using `Handler`.

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            private Handler mHandler;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (mHandler != null)
                        return true;
                    mHandler = new Handler();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mAction, 500);
                    return false;
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (mHandler == null)
                       return true;
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAction);
                    mHandler = null;
                    return false;
            }
                return false;
            }

            Runnable mAction = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                 
                    String s = tv.getText().toString();
                    tv.setText(s + "E");
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                }
            };
        });
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511423/android-repeat-action-on-pressing-and-holding-a-button/10511800#10511800).
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

Make a boolean member variable to use as a flag for filling the textview. In the on touch down set that boolean to true, and start a runnable which sets the text, and then starts another runnable. This creates a loop.
In the on touch up, set the boolean to false, and the loop will stop. Something like this (untested):

```
private boolean mFillTextView = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                mFillTextView = true;
                Handler mHandler= new Handler();
                mHandler.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(), 300);
                return false;
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                mFillTextView =false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mFillTextView){
            mTextView.setText(mTextView.getText()+"a");
            mHandler.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(), 300);

        })};
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start a looping thread that populates your `TextView` when you receive the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event

You can then use `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event to stop that thread from running

Inside your thread you will need to invoke back to the UI thread before you will be able to modify the text inside the `TextView`