# Continuously calling method until button is pressed

Tags: android

I am working on Android project in which I want to call a function repetitively until I dont release touch from button so which event should I use?I am currently using ontouch listener but that calls the function once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android repeat action on pressing and holding a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511423/android-repeat-action-on-pressing-and-holding-a-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an onTouchListener to detect the button press.  Then you can use a Handler or AlarmManager to call your event until a certain condition is reached:

```
this.handlerMethod = new MethodHandler(this);
boolean myCondition = false;

imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        if (myCondition == false) {
          handlerMethod.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 55000);

        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});



/**
 * private static handler so there are no leaked activities.
 */
private static class MethodHandler extends Handler {

    private final WeakReference<Home> activity;

    public MyTimeHandler(Home activity) {
        this.activity = new WeakReference<Home>(activity);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (activity.get() != null) {

            activity.get().myMethod();
        }

        sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 55000);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such listener that will be called many times while you hold your finger on a button. This will pollute the UI message queue.

What you can do is to implement `OnTouchListener` which has `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` method. The `MotionEvent` object can be used for distinguishing actions such as `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`. Those are called when you press and release button respectively.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN

So, after you detect the `ACTION_DOWN` event, call your function as many times as you need. Stop calling it when you receive `ACTION_UP`.

Be careful though, if you call your function on the UI thread there is a risk that you will block it. If that happens, consider using a `Handler` or a background thread.