# Checking, if two buttons are clicked at the same time

Tags: android, android-button

Is there any way to check, if **two buttons are clicked at the same time** ? I wrote a switch-statement in the button click listeners, but I can't check when these buttons are clicked ate the same time.

Here is a my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            Log.d("MR.bool", "Button1 was clicked ");
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Log.d("MR.bool", "Button2 was clicked ");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of functionality do you want? please explain briefly.

Comment: I have different logic each buttons,but Also I want another action in same click these buttons @Vasudev Vyas

Comment: You can not click both button at once.. What exactly is your Question here ?

Comment: check this vogela article https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html

Comment: Yes that's right :( @ADM

Answer (score 0):

I think there are always milliseconds between the clicks of the buttons. So they will never be clicked at the same time.

You can go with `setOnTouchListener` and while Button1 is pressed you can wait for Button2 is pressed

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                    // wait here for Button2.Click

                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    // Button Release Event

                }
                return true;
            }

        });
```

You need call this with a `Runnable` on a `Handler` as mentioned in this questions answer: [android repeat action on pressing and holding a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511423/android-repeat-action-on-pressing-and-holding-a-button/10511800)

Comment: Thanks for your response,but I did not understand correctly milliseconds logic  @K. Dexter

Comment: It wont happen that you click 2 buttons at the exact same moment. So the only way to recognize some similar behavior is to check, if while button 1 is pressed, another button is pressed

Comment: @K.Dexter its logical.